# What is the proper method for calculating the Coefficient of Variation of a rate?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, coefficient-of-variation, harmonic-mean

I have been asked to evaluate the variation between movement rates of fish within different systems (rates are in km/day).  I have between 25-100 samples in each system.  I understand that when reporting the average rate for a given system, it is more appropriate to use the harmonic mean than the arithmetic mean.

If that's the case, how would one calculate the Coefficient of Variation ($CV = \sigma/\mu$) for the movement rates in each system?  Does the standard deviation become the (arithmetic) mean difference of each sample from the harmonic mean?

Comment: The harmonic mean is equivalent to applying the arithmetic mean to the reciprocals of the rates: that is, rather than expressing the data in km/day, express them in day/km.  Then proceed as usual to compute the CV.  You should verify that the univariate distributions of the data, when re-expressed in this way, are approximately symmetric: that is what would justify the re-expression and give meaning to the CV in the first place.

Comment: Thank you.  Is it appropriate to report 1/sd(rate in day/km) as the standard deviation of the rates in each system?

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry, I'm realizing that's probably not right.  For reporting purposes, is it possible to re-express the standard deviation of the movement rates in each system in km/day?